# Send datas with axios to each change in a input ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, handle

I'm writing this little topic because i have a little question. (the code in this topic is not my true code, just a example).

I would like to send the input `name_contact` content to each change. But I only manage to send it with a `button`. 
So my question is: 
Is it possible? And how can I do it?

```
    export default class FormPage extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = initialState;
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

     removeClick(i){
      let users = [...this.state.users];
      users.splice(i, 1);
      this.setState({ users });
     }

     showMessage = (bool) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({
        showMessage: true
       });
      }, 2000);
     if (this.state.Showing) return;
      this.setState({ Show: true, Showing: true });
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ Show: false, Showing: false });
      }, 2000);
     }

     showMessageFalse = (bool) => {
      this.setState({
       showMessage: false
       });
      this.setState(initialState);
     }

     handleChange(event) {
      const InputValue = event.target.value;
      const stateField = event.target.name;
      this.setState({
        [stateField]: InputValue,
      });
      console.log(this.state);
     }

     async handleSubmit(event) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({ loading: false });
      }, 2000);

     event.preventDefault();
     const {
       name_contact='',
     } = this.state;

     await axios.post(
      ' MY_endpoint API',
      {
        name: `${name_contact}`);
      }

  render() {

    const { loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <ExpansionPanel title="Contacts" expandedTitle="Contacts" titleIcon="done_all" ><div>
          <Container>
            <div id="normal"><label id='title2'>Detail du contact</label></div><br/>
              <Row align="center">
                <Col id= "color" sm={3}> <label> Name: </label></Col> <Col id= "color" sm={3}><Input placeholder="Nom complet" type="string" name="name_contact" value={this.state.name_contact} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br /> </Col>
              </Row>
          </Container>
          </div>
        </ExpansionPanel>

      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <br /><br /><div id="deb"><Button type="submit" value="Show" onClick={this.showMessageFalse.bind(null, true)} > Update </Button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to call `handleSubmit` in `handleChange`, but nothing does. (you don't need to give me the good answer, but a track will make me very happy)
Thanks,

Comment: So you want to send a request to your server each time the user inputs ANY key?

Comment: @r3dst0rm basically, yes. i want to send the input if anyone do any key in this input.  I'm doing this, when i'm clicking in the buttom, axios is doing the job. But it doesn't work at each new key in the input

Comment: Replace `handleChange(event) {` with `handleChange = (event) => {`, that way you correctly bind the this value and it should execute without any issue. Otherwise you could replace `onChange={this.handleChange}` with `onChange{this.handleChange.bind(this)}` which is less elegant in my opinion. And inside handleChange call the handleSubmit function

Comment: @r3dst0rm thanks, it's working. Now I have the problem of delay of a change at each change but I will find alone. It is up to you, if you wish, to put your solution in the answers, so that I can validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comment section, you can do the following:

Change your `handleChange(event) {` to a arrow function with correct this binding like so: `handleChange = (event) => {` or alternatively bind it like so *(which wouldn't be not that elegant in my opinion)*:

```js
<Input placeholder="Nom complet" type="string" name="name_contact" value={this.state.name_contact} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
```

Then, you just need to call the endpoint from your `handleChange` function. E.g. by calling the `handleSubmit` routine. Or just call the endpoint by simply using axios to make it silent.